# Is it possible to execute a file then wait until the file changed before executing again in MS Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a program that executes a file after it has changed
Here's my code:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
cd executionFiles
set /p Data1=<execute.bat
pause
:loop
set /p Data2=<execute.bat
pause
if NOT %Data1%==%Data2% (
    set Data1=%Data2%
    start call execute.bat
)
pause
timeout 10 /nobreak >nul
pause
goto loop
```

Right now, it just closes Command prompt right when it gets to the "IF" command. It doesn't show any error message, or it closes before I can see it. So I don't know what error I did here

Is it possible to even do this with a few tweaks to my code or do I have to completely rewrite the thing; and what do I need to change?

Comment: Without knowing what the output of `execute.bat` is, we're guessing. Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in thing1/2. When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.

Comment: Oh - you do realise that `set /p ...` will read the file only up to the first newline, don't you?

Comment: The `set /P` lines store the first line of `execute.bat` to variable `Data1` and `Data2`, resp.; that's not what you want, is it? For the `if` syntax: use quotation, like `if not "%Data1%"=="%Data2%" (`…

Comment: I think that is the intention @aschipfl, it appears that the intention is to determine, after the `pause` has completed, if the first line of the file has changed. Also `start call execute.bat` should, I think, be just `Call execute.bat`